# Python: Error in getting Tkinter's Entry value with button

Tags: python, tkinter

Well since this is my first day learning Python I hope people don't mind for newbie question

I have a Tkinter with GUI layout like this:

```
Label(base, text="Site URL: ",width=15).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=STICKY,pady=5)
entry1 = Entry(base, width=40).grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=STICKY,pady=5)
mybtn = Button(base, text="Run",command=s.initiate(entry1.get())).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=STICKY,padx=10,pady=5)
```

`STICKY` is `N+S+E+W` for grid layout, `s` from `s.initiate` is a module I imported like this (on the top of my main file):

```
import spider as s
```

and `spider` module content is like this:

```
import tkMessageBox

def initiate(url):
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Spider", url)
```

when I'm trying to compile my code this error comes out:

```
File "index.py", line 18, in <module>
  mybtn = Button(base, text="Run",command=s.initiate(entry1.get())).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=STICKY,padx=10,pady=5)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong in getting value from `Entry` on button click?

My guess is `get()` is being run while compiling the code, but `entry1` has not been registered to the Tkinter gui by Python yet. If this is true, can anyone show me a workaround from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
entry1=Entry(base, width=40)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=STICKY,pady=5)
```

The problem is you are using a variable whose value is `None` & when you do `None.get()`, you get an error. Its value is `None` because `entry1` has the value of the last function called,which was `grid()` which always returns `None`.

## Edit:

The automatic calling of function is because *you are* calling it.
If you want to send some arguments to a function, do this:

`command=lambda:myfunc(myargs)`

Also, if you don't want to send any arguments the simple `command=myfunc` would suffice(Notice that there are **no parenthesis** here)

Comment: no error, but Tkinter button behavior becomes weird, it runs the `command` even when i didnt press the button (and if i press the button, nothing happens). In my code case, it alerts nothing, then nothing happens